# Create favicon from .svg in lumen

Tags: laravel, svg, favicon, lumen

I'm starting to use lumen and I have to add a favicon but is .svg.

How do I create a favicon for all devices or sizes from a picture .svg?

Comment: This really isn't a programming question. Try using an image editor that can edit SVGs and export as ICO. Try [InkScape](https://inkscape.org/), it's free and open-source.

Comment: Here is one more nice option. http://iconifier.net/

Answer (score 1):

Most browsers don't support SVG as a favicon. So your question is "how to turn my SVG picture into several PNG pictures?"

My advice is to use [Real Favicon Generator](http://realfavicongenerator.net/). It allows you to upload your SVG picture, edit its design platform-per-platform and download the generated pictures and HTML code.

Full disclosure: I'm the author of this site.

Comment: Thank you for your observation , I'll deal with that page.